# How to access arbitrary file in OS X 10.10 app?

Tags: xcode, swift, file-io, osx-yosemite

I am teaching myself Apple Development with a Swift OS X 10.10 App. I want to pass a file URL to NSXMLParser. That file is large, and on a seperate disk from my app. I create the NSURL, but when I check it with checkPromisedItemIsReachableAndReturnError(), I always get a "No such file or directory error".

It looks like whe I run my app in Xcode, something is prepending the app's development directory into my file path, so `"/Volumes/bigdrive/data.xml"` becomes `"/Users/charlweed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dataskunk-ghkiumvdkopxarhavynetidlqxio/Build/Products/Debug/file:/Volumes/bigdrive/data.xml"`

I did not enable Sandbox, or iCloud when I created the project. I thought I might need to use NSURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() anyway, but it always returns true. What am I doing wrong? Here is a test function in Swift,I don't know objective-c, but I expect I can figure out an objective-c answer:

```
func accessFile() {
    /**I belive this URI is correct, becuase everything after the file:// works in the OS X bash*/
    let xmlInFilePath = "file:///Volumes/Seagate_1tib/projects/dataskunk/wasteproduct.xml"
    if let xmlInFileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(xmlInFilePath)
    {
        println("Unwrapped \(xmlInFileURL)")
        var securityURLBS = xmlInFileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        if securityURLBS
        {
            var xmlFileError: NSError?
            if xmlInFileURL.checkPromisedItemIsReachableAndReturnError(&xmlFileError)
            {
                println("Can access file. huray!")
                /** Use the file URL**/
            }
            else
            {
                /** This Always happens with a "No such file or directory " :( **/
                println("\(xmlFileError)")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println("Could not get Security Scoped Resource")
        }
        xmlInFileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    }
    else
    {
        log(" NSURL.fileURLWithPath() returned nil for \(xmlInFilePath)")
    }
}
```

Here is the dump of the error:

> Unwrapped file:/Volumes/Seagate_1tib/projects/dataskunk/apple_rss.xml -- file:///Users/charlweed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keepass2Keyring-ghkiumvdkopxarhavynetidlqxio/Build/Products/Debug/
>
> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “wasteproduct.xml” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
>
> UserInfo=0x61000006f9c0 NSURL=file:/Volumes/Seagate_1tib/projects/dataskunk/wasteproduct.xml -- file:///Users/charlweed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keepass2Keyring-ghkiumvdkopxarhavynetidlqxio/Build/Products/Debug/,
>
> NSFilePath=/Users/charlweed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keepass2Keyring-ghkiumvdkopxarhavynetidlqxio/Build/Products/Debug/file:/Volumes/Seagate_1tib/projects/dataskunk/wasteproduct.xml,
>
> NSUnderlyingError=0x610000044a10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"})

Comment: Just to let you know if the string has the prefix file:// you need to create an url using NSURL method filePathForURL() then you can use the path extension to extract the path from that NSURL

Comment: What specifically do you mean? There is no method "filePathForURL" on the NSURL class. At least there is currently no documentation for it, and the compiler complains that it does not exist when I try to reference it.

Comment: Sorry it is called fileURLWithPath

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that `NSURL.fileURLWithPath()` does not take a URL-path as an argument, only a filesystem-path. So `"file:///Volumes/disk/file.xml"` is wrong, `"/Volumes/disk/file.xml"` is correct.

The mangling is NSURL prefixing the current directory onto what it thinks is a relative filesystem-path String.

Comment: file:// is the url scheme. A path doesn't have it. You can't add file:// to a path.Ttry using it at the Finder's go to folder command-shift-G